# Referencing User Control on separate .aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, user-controls

I have a .ASPX page that pulls in a user control from a master page, and I am trying to call an `update()` method in one user control (hereby referred to as control1), to an update panel that is in another user control (hereby referred to as control2).

I have set a reference to control2 in the .ascx page of control1:

```
<%@ Reference Control="~/controls/MobileMenu.ascx" %>
```

I have instanced control2 and am trying to call the public method from the code-behind of control1:

```
   controls_MobileMenu mobi = new controls_MobileMenu();
      mobi.Update(ThisCustomer);
```

Here is the method that fires in control2:

```
   public void Update(Customer customer)
{
    getItemNums(customer);
}

    protected void getItemNums(Customer customer)
{
    int numItems = ShoppingCart.NumItems(customer.CustomerID, CartTypeEnum.WishCart);

    if (numItems > 0)
    {

        lbwishlist.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        lbwishlist.Text = "My Wishlist ( " + numItems + " )";

    }
    else
    {
        lbwishlist.ForeColor = Color.White;
        lbwishlist.Text = "My Wishlist";
    }
}
```

When my code runs though, and I step through it, my lbwishlist linkbutton is `null` and the code throws a null reference exception.  Can anyone explain why this is considered null when the other control calls it?  And is there any way around this?

Comment: It is null because you are creating a new instance of the control in code here `controls_MobileMenu mobi = new controls_MobileMenu()` so the markup is simply not prcessed so none of the controls defined in the markup will be instantiated. Do you have an instance of `controls_MobileMenu` anywhere on your page? If so you need to reference that instance not create a new one.

Comment: I guess that does make sense, but I'm still at a loss for how to do that, this is a bit conceptually confusing for me.  From top to bottom I have a master page which hosts this control, then I have an aspx page, and on this aspx page, I have another control.  In this control, when certain events are fired, how can I access my public method in the control on the masterpage to make the update panel run?

Comment: In the master page create a property that exposes the user control. In the user control in the .aspx page, create a property of the type of the control in the master page , then in the aspx page pass in a reference to the property in the masterpage along the lines of `OtherUserControl.SomeProperty = ((MyMasterPage)Master).MasterUserControlProperty`